# ngModel cant bind to async property Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue, now when I start my app I have an async call like so..

```
getData() {
   this._dataService.getData().subscribe((result) => {
     this.data = result
   })
}
```

now the data I get back looks something like this

```
data = {
    value1: null,
    value2: null,
    value3: null,
    value4: null,
    value5: null,
    etc..
}
```

now in my HTML I'm doing this..

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data.value1" />
<input [(ngModel)]="data.value2" />
```

etc..

so when I run my app, I get errors saying cant bind to undefined meaning that when the page renders data hasnt been retrieved yet

now normally I would do something like this...

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data?.value2" />
```

but I get this error `Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment`

is there anyway around this?

I dont really want to do the following

```
setData() {
   this.value1 = this.data.value1;
   etc...
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize data in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your input inside a `*ngIf="data"`.

```
<form *ngIf="data">
    <input [(ngModel)]="data.value1" />
    <input [(ngModel)]="data.value2" />
</form>
```

Comment: not the most elegant solution but does work.. thanks

Comment: Doing so will make the form display only when data is filled up with the correct informations. Don't forget to check my answer as the correct answer please :)

Comment: Given your example this is probably the most elegent solution you will get besides initializing data with an empty object. If you don't want to use ngIf nor initialize data with an empty value you should have a look at resolvers. You can use resolvers to load data before your component is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the data object at first.

```
data = {
    value1: null,
    value2: null,
    value3: null,
    value4: null,
    value5: null, 
}

getData() {
   this._dataService.getData().subscribe((result) => {
     this.data = result
   })
}
```

Comment: did u use `<input [(ngModel)]="data?.value2" />
`

Comment: it should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4eqrhw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the getData method. result object can be undefined. you have to check it first. use console.log or network tab in the browser and check the response.

```js
getData() {
   this._dataService.getData().subscribe((result) => {

     console.log(result)
     this.data = result 

   })
}
```

however you can simply do this for working. this will work but not the correct way.

```
getData() {
   this._dataService.getData().subscribe((result) => {


     this.data = result?result:this.data 

   })
}
```